# RLock /storage/8D8B-150E/github.com/my-username/App/go.mod: function not implemented

Tags: go, goland

I am having an issue while creating a new module in go with this command: `go mod init <moduleName>` it successfully created go.mod file but later then throws this error `go: RLock /storage/mySdCard/github.com/my-username/App/go.mod: function not implemented` & its not allowing me to install any go packages! Please help me to resolve this error or how can I fix it!!

I ran this command:
`go mod init myApp`

The output I got:
`go: creating new go.mod: module myApp`
`go: updating go.mod: Lock /storage/8D8B-150E/Go/src/github.com/my-username/App/go.mod: function not implemented`

Comment: It's very difficult to debug code we can't see. Can you update your question with the code that's generating the error?

Comment: Its throwing the error whenever I try to create a new module in go!!! And btw I am using termux!

Comment: You just said it successfully created the module.  So is it successful or not? Please show the eact command(s) you ran to produce the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `go` command uses file-locking to ensure that the `go.mod` file is read in a consistent state if you run multiple `go` commands concurrently.

The `RLock /storage/mySdCard/github.com/my-username/App/go.mod: function not implemented` error that you're seeing indicates that the filesystem containing the `go.mod` file (`/storage/mySdCard`) does not support read-locking. (On most Unix-like operating systems, we use the `flock` system call.)

If you can't configure the filesystem to support locking and it isn't practical for you to work within a different filesystem that does, please file an issue at https://golang.org/issue/new, and mention [issue #37461](https://golang.org/issue/37461) (which is closely related) in the issue description.